# Installing Git, Curl, and Expat from Source

Tags: rhel, git, source

I have a RHEL 6.4 VM provisioned by my company's internal KVM.

We are having some trouble using `yum` (`Cannot retrieve repository metadata`, which I've confirmed in this case is peculiar to my company's internal cloud), so I have to build Git from source.

Downloading the RPM file and issuing

```
sudo yum localinstall ....rpm
```

Gives me the same `Cannot retrieve repository metadata` error.

Issuing

```
sudo rpm -ivh ....rpm
```

Fails with an `error: Failed dependencies` and then lists all the packages I need to install. I assume I could find the download links for all of them, but I've tried this before and was unable to find the download links for the right versions for the right packages.

*The following code actually works, thanks to [@slm's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/107778/7453):*

```
wget ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/dag/redhat/el6/en/x86_64/extras/RPMS/perl-Git-1.7.9.6-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/git-1.7.9.6-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh perl-Git-1.7.9.6-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm git-1.7.9.6-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
```

If I just download the git code, untar it, and build it, like:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/git-1.8.5.tar.gz
tar -xvf git-1.8.5.tar.gz
cd git-1.8.5
./configure
make
make install
```

I receive the following error when cloning from the `http://` protocol:

```
fatal: Unable to find remote helper for 'http'
```

Googling told me that I needed curl-devel and expat. I can not use yum, so I went and built those as well:

```
cd ..
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.34.0.tar.gz
tar -xvf curl-7.34.0.tar.gz
cd curl-7.34.0
./configure
make
make install

cd ..
wget http://downloads.sourceforge.net/expat/expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
tar expat-2.1.0.tar.gz
cd expat-2.1.0
./configure
make
make install
```

However, upon rebuilding Git, I receive the same error. After Googling more I determined that I needed to pass the following parameters to Git's `./configure`:

```
cd git-1.8.5
./configure --with-curl=<curl_install_path> --with-expat=<expat_install_path>
```

However, I couldn't determine where the curl and expat install paths were located.

So what I did instead was build Git, curl, and expat using the `./configure --prefix=/path/to/desired/install/path`

```
mkdir curl
cd curl-7.34.0
./configure --prefix=/home/downloads/curl
...
mkdir expat
cd expat-2.1.0
./configure --prefix=/home/downloads/expat
...
mkdir git
cd git-1.8.5
./configure --prefix=/home/downloads/git --with-curl=/home/downloads/curl --with-expat=/home/downloads/expat
...
```

and from this I was able to clone with Git from the `http` protocol. However, this violates the Linux file structure.

Two Questions:

1. When building Git from source, you need to include the curl and expat install paths to `./configure`. Where are these install paths when installing curl and expat without the `prefix` argument?
2. I learned that I needed curl and expat's install paths when I got an error and searched for it. Are there any other programs I need to tell Git so I don't get errors in the future?

Comment: another option might be simply using an ssh url instead of a http url.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I would suggest not installing these items from source directly but rather harness the power of your package manager to still maintain these packages.

#### locally installing

You can use a command line tool such as `curl` or `wget` to still download the packages necessary to install them either using `yum` or `rpm` directly.

```
$ sudo yum localinstall some.rpm
-or-
$ sudo rpm -ivh some.rpm
```

I would suggest looking to the repositories [RepoForge](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/) as well as [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) for RPMs. For example the `git` packages are here.

- http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/

A simple command in the terminal will download it:

```
$ wget http://pkgs.repoforge.org/git/git-1.7.10.4-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm
```

#### Rebuilding a source RPM

On the off chance you have to have the latest versions, you can still make use of RPMs but rather than download the `.rpm` version of a package, you'll want to get the `.src.rpm` version. These can be rebuilt using the following command:

```
$ rpmbuild --rebuild some.src.rpm
```

#### Rebuilding a tar.gz using a donor source RPM

You can also take your `.tar.gz` tarballs and reuse the `.spec` file that's included in the above `.src.rpm`. You do this through the following commands.

```
$ mkdir -p ~/rpm/{BUILD,RPMS,SOURCES,SPECS,SRPMS,tmp}
```

Then create a `~/.rpmmacros` file.

```
%packager Your Name
%_topdir /home/YOUR HOME DIR/rpm
%_tmppath /home/YOUR HOME DIR/rpm/tmp
```

Now we're ready to "install" the donor `.src.rpm`.

```
$ rpm -ivh some.src.rpm
```

This will deposit a tarball and a `.spec` file in your `~/rpm` directories. You can then edit this `.spec` file and replace the tarball with the newer one.

Now to rebuild it:

```
$ rpmbuild -ba ~/rpm/SPECS/some.spec
```

This will create a `.rpm` and a new `.src.rpm` file once it's complete.

#### Additional tips

You can use the tool `yum-builddep` to make sure you have all the required RPMs installed before getting started.

```
$ sudo yum-builddep some.src.rpm
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, my yum isn't working. `sudo yum localinstall ....rpm` gave me the same yum error as usual (Cannot retrieve repository metadata). `sudo rpm -ivh ....rpm` gave me `error: Failed dependencies: <package_name> is needed by git-all' I'll try the src method.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - you need to download all the required .rpm files and do a `sudo rpm -ivh 1.rpm 2.rpm 3.rpm...`.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - I caution you I've been dealing with this stuff for 20+ years. Compiling these from source can be painful, more so than dealing with gathering up the required RPMs!

Comment: I have had difficulty finding and downloading all the required .rpm files, for example, `git-all` requires `emacs-git`, `git`, `git-arch`, each of which require other rpms. I'll try the RepoForge however and report back

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - yes the advantage of staying with the repo is all the required pkgs are there!

Comment: `sudo rpmbuild --rebuild ....src.rpm` resulted in `error: Failed build dependencies: <package_name> is needed by git...'

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - yes you're not going to cheat anything with one approach over the other. They all need the dependencies installed in one way or another. In general it's safer to avoid having to build the software from source, using the packages saves you in having to figure out configure switches etc.

Comment: Well it worked, as per my updated question. Thanks Slim!

Comment: @MatthewMoisen - terrific. If you feel your issues been resolved please mark this as the accepted answer so that others will not continue to try answering it unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3):

The install path is easy enough to find. Most `configure` scripts are pretty standard, and the usually have a `-h` flag that prints a help message. 
Have a look at git's:

```
$ ./configure -h | grep -A 2 Insta
Installation directories:
  --prefix=PREFIX         install architecture-independent files in PREFIX
                          [/usr/local]
```

So, you installed `curl` using `--prefix=/home/downloads/curl` and it was detected by `git` with `--with-curl=/home/downloads/curl`. Therefore, if you had installed to the default locations, you would have run `--with-curl=/usr/local/`.

As for other possible problems, no idea. You'll cross that bridge when you get to it.

---

On a more general note, I recommend you try searching for RPM packages before installing from source. You don't need `yum` to install RPM packages, you can simply do:

```
rpm -i rpmfile.rpm
```

I found RHEL 6 RPMs for [`git`](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/18007488/dir/redhat_el_6/com/git-1.7.9.6-1.el6.rfx.x86_64.rpm.html) and [`curl`](http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/23487533/dir/redhat_el_6/com/curl-7.31.0-23.2.x86_64.rpm.html) on [rpm.pbone.net](http://rpm.pbone.net/). Couldn't find a RHEL 6 one for `expat` but there were various for Fedora and CentOS, one of them would probably work for you too.

Comment: Promote these repos: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL & http://repoforge.org/. Heed the warnings on this CentOS wiki when mixing repositories: http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

Comment: @slm is repoforge actually safe? I have ran into quite a few issues with rpmforge over the years.

Comment: @jordanm - I use it. They've been segregating packages recently to address the mixing of it, you'll see rfx packages now, which can be some of the problematic ones, but in general I've used it. Mixing RF with others is where it gets messy.

Answer (score -1):

Answering 1. The install path to additional packages depends on how they are installed. If you install them as admin, they should be installed to standard `/usr` or `/usr/share` locations. Someplace which is already on system path. You can find this from `config.log` or other logs left by the configure script. Furthermore, some admins might choose to install these packages on `/opt` directory which stands for 'optional packages'. However, if you install them as a mortal user, you can install them anywhere you have write access, most likely your `/home`. I normally use a location such as `/home/myname/curl-install`.