# How to install custom source from git using my package manager in Gentoo?

Tags: software-installation, git, gentoo, emerge

I would like to **install custom source** from a **git** repository, but **using my package manager** (emerge for portage).

### Background

I have installed Gentoo using EFI using [Sakaki's tutorial](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki's_EFI_Install_Guide), so I have already emerged `dev-vcs/git`.

The packages that I want are for installing [Canonical's Snapd](http://snapcraft.io/docs/core/install) (background reading from [Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/06/goodbye-apt-and-yum-ubuntus-snap-apps-are-coming-to-distros-everywhere/)), and their instructions are:

> Gentoo
>
> Install [snap-confine.ebuild](https://github.com/zyga/snap-confine-gentoo) and [snapd.ebuild](https://github.com/snapcore/snapd)
>
> '# enable the snapd systemd service:
>
> `sudo systemctl enable --now snapd.service`

### Steps Tried that Didn't Work

### Try 1

First I tried to add the prerequisite git .ebuilds as repositories by putting them in my `/etc/portage/repos.conf/` directory (two separate entries).  I'll post *one* here as an example:

```bash
[zyga-snap-confine]

# Snapd build dependency #1
# Maintainer: obscured

location = /usr/local/portage/zyga-snap-confine
sync-type = git
sync-uri = https://github.com/zyga/snap-confine-gentoo.git
priority = 60
auto-sync = yes
```

I synced the repos, `emaint sync --repo zyga-snap-confine`.  And then I tried finding the packages that I wanted via both `emerge --search` and `eix`.  **No luck.**

It tossed errors about missing layout, a master = gentoo entry...I realize that there was missing metadata, but I had high hopes.

### Try 2

I finally found a reference with ***what*** to do with an ebuild.  In the official [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Sakaki's_EFI_Install_Guide), and from other posts here ([Installing Git, Curl, and Expat from Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/107775/installing-git-curl-and-expat-from-source?rq=1)) and here ([How to package software in Funtoo/Gentoo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82216/how-to-package-software-in-funtoo-gentoo)), I decided to:

```bash
root@Gentoo ~ # cd /opt
root@Gentoo opt # git clone https://github.com/zyga/snap-confine-gentoo.git
root@Gentoo opt # cd snap-confine-gentoo
root@Gentoo snap-confine-gentoo # ebuild snap-confine-1.0.32.ebuild manifest clean merge
```

However, it returned errors:

```bash
Appending / to PORTDIR_OVERLAY...
!!! Repository 'x-' is missing masters attribute in '/metadata/layout.conf'
!!! Set 'masters = gentoo' in this file for future compatibility
ebuild: /opt/snap-confine-gentoo/snap-confine-1.0.32.ebuild: does not seem to have a valid PORTDIR structure
```

### Preferred Solution

I'm relatively new to Gentoo and am self-taught on Linux, and I couldn't find a tutorial on repo maintenance in the Gentoo forums (there is a [developer's guide](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/), but it assumes a lot of knowledge).  An ideal answer will provide both the cli method (I assume using `git clone` ...and `./configure`?) as well as the package manager version.

Even if I have to create my own git repository to add missing metadata and layout files - I would prefer to manage the snapd installation that way.

Comment: You need to put the ebuilds in their own directory structure as so: /usr/local/portage/category/package i.e /usr/local/portage/snapcore/snap-confine and for the other one it would be /usr/local/portage/snap-core/snapd but you should really figure out which existing category the package fits in first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based off of @likewhoa comments above, the structure of the ebuild needed to be massaged.  The creators did not have recent portage structure in mind when creating their git repositories.

### For Command-line

*(an ebuild without portage directory structure)* 
Within `/usr/local/portage/` I decided that **snap-confine** belonged under category `sys-apps`

From bash root prompt:

```bash
cd /usr/local/portage
git clone https://github.com/zyga/snap-confine-gentoo.git
cd snap-confine-gentoo
mkdir -pv sys-apps/snap-confine
# the Manifest file will be recreated later
rm -v Manifest
mv -v snap-confine-1.0.32.ebuild sys-apps/snap-confine/
# to avoid errors, you need your masters = gentoo reference
mkdir -v metadata
echo 'masters = gentoo' > metadata/layout.conf 
cd sys-apps/snap-confine
ebuild snap-confine-1.0.32.ebuild manifest clean merge
```

As it turns out, the .ebuild wasn't properly formed with correct dependencies, but I think these steps provide a good tutorial - based off of:

1. https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Basic_guide_to_write_Gentoo_Ebuilds
2. https://devmanual.gentoo.org/quickstart/

### For Portage management

Based off of other Gentoo repositories, I recommended to the developer to create a single repo containing both the **snap-confine** and **snapd** ebuilds under the package categories `sys-apps` and `app-emulation`, respectively.

Then, we created a *metadata/layout.conf* file containing `masters = gentoo` to avoid portage compatibility complaints.  Developer guidance also required that we have a *profiles/repo_name* file with the repo's name identified.  Within each package's folder, we created a *metadata.xml* file and then ran `repoman manifest` to generate the *Manifest* file.

Lastly, a user needs to create an entry within `/etc/portage/repos.conf/`, the instructions for which are expertly detailed on the [sakaki-tools github repo](https://github.com/sakaki-/sakaki-tools)